# Python2 tokenization and add to dictonary

Tags: python, dictionary, token

I have some texts that I need to generate tokens splitting by space. Furthermore, I need to remove all punctuation, as I need to remove everything inside double braces [[...]] (including the double braces).

Each token I will put on a dictionary as the key that will have a list of values.

I have tried regex to remove these double braces patterns, if-elses, but I can't find a solution that works. For the moment I have:

```
tokenDic = dict()
splittedWords =  re.findall(r'\[\[\s*([^][]*?)]]',  docs[doc], re.IGNORECASE) 
tokenStr = splittedWords.split()

for token in tokenStr:
    tokenDic[token].append(value);
```

Comment: split returns a list of the values that were in the string separated by white space. Ex 'my stuff'.split() would return ['my','stuff']. So if you are trying to add only the first word you would want splittedWords.split()[0]. Which will return the first one. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: No... In fact I have to return all my string without everything that are inside double braces [[]]. But if inside of this double braces I have a *pipe* or a *#*, I need to return also the second element (after the  *pipe* and the  *#*)

Comment: I will change the question to just one part of it to make easier

Comment: So the first part of the problem at least is just that you can't remove all of the '[' and ']' characters from the string?

Comment: Yes! I want to have my string without everything that is inside [[]]. Then remove all the punctuation and store token by token as key of a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove everything inside [[]] you can use re.sub and you already have the correct regex so just do this.

```
 x = [[hello]]w&o%r*ld^$
 y = re.sub("\[\[\s*([^][]*?)]]","",x)
 z = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z\s]","",y)
 print(z)
```

This prints "world"

Comment: Thanks! But it was not really this. [[sas]]sad[as] should return **sadas**. I have to remove/cut off everything inside double braces including the double braces. So on this case **[[sas]] will be removed**. I was thinking on a  regex, is not possible?

Comment: OH Okay sorry really didn't understand the problem.

Comment: Okay is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Almost, it does not remove punctuation, and special characters (like {, (, §, ! etc)

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand why you have 'z = re.sub()'. Is not y enought?

Comment: Because I am dumb, I fixed it. Sorry copied the wrong text. The y sub removes everything in the [[]] but the z sub removes all other characters that aren't letters. So it would remove all special characters and punctuation.

Comment: Thanks! But still is not removing the  pipes, this is the only special character that is not being removed

Comment: Just remove the pipes from the regex, I forgot you don't need or statements in a regex. I fixed the one in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import re
value_list = []
inp_str = 'blahblah[[blahblah]]thi ng1[[junk]]hmm'
tokenDic = dict()
#remove everything in double brackets
bracket_stuff_removed = re.sub(r'\[\[[^]]*\]\]', '', inp_str)

#function to keep only letters and digits
clean_func = lambda x: 97 <= ord(x.lower()) <= 122 or 48 <= ord(x) <= 57

for token in bracket_stuff_removed.split(' '):
    cleaned_token = ''.join(filter(clean_func, token))
    tokenDic[cleaned_token] = list(value_list)

print(tokenDic)
```

Output:

```
{'blahblahthi': [], 'ng1hmm': []}
```

As for appending to the list, I don't have enough info right now to tell you the best way in your situation.

If you want to set the value when you're adding the key, do this:

```
tokenDic[cleaned_token] = [val1, val2, val3]
```

If you want to set the values after the key has been added, do this:

```
val_to_add = "something"
if tokenDic.get(cleaned_token, -1) == -1:
    print('ERROR', cleaned_token, 'does not exist in dict')
else:
    tokenDic[cleaned_token].append(val_to_add)
```

If you want to directly append to the dict in both cases, you'll need to use defaultdict(list) instead of dict.. then if the key does not exist in the dict, it will create it, make the value an empty list, and then add your value.

Comment: Thanks! It was this! In addition, If I have a list of things that I want to add as value on my dictionary, should I put  tokenDic[cleaned_token].append(value) ?

Comment: I put my responce in the edit, because I'm not sure how to format it here

Comment: Ok, thanks, but doing this I get 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append''

Comment: That's because you have a value in the dictionary which is a string.  You need to initialize the value to be a list.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Put this as you "val_to_add = "something"" and still got the error

Comment: When I first answered your question, i put something like this in the for loop:  
tokenDic[cleaned_token] = value          
I made value a string temporarily, because I didn't have much info on how you were trying to load the values in.  When I added the values info, I changed it to a list so the appends would work.  I think you're still using a string for the values.